# Delete device connector in Visio's Ethernet shape

Tags: visio

I have a really annoying problem. I am trying to create a Visio 2016 drawing with an Ethernet shape (Network -> Network and Peripherals) and for the life of me, I cannot seem to delete device endpoints after I drop the shape upon my canvas. I mean these things:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to delete these?

Answer (score 3):

Select the shape and you'll see a (yellow) control handle for each point.  Drag it inside the bounds of the core shape and it will disappear.

Comment: I already know how to hide it. I wanted to know how to actually delete it.

Comment: This shape carries 64 control points and 64 corresponding geometry sections in a sub-shape.  To remove one, you'd need to delete the control row and the corresponding geometry section.  What are you hoping to end up with?